# PulseAudio crashing after minutes of use

Tags: pulseaudio, manjaro

I've been using Manjaro linux for a while now and this one bug is completely stopping me from being productive at all. Seemingly randomly my PulseAudio will crash, and I won't be able to connect to the PulseAudio server. I have tried solutions I've found elsewhere of deleting configs and restarting the server but none of these have fixed the issue.

Here is the output of `pulseaudio -vvvv`:

```
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
D: [pulseaudio] core-rtclock.c: Timer slack is set to 50 us.
D: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: RealtimeKit worked.
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 14.2
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation CFLAGS: Not yet supported on meson
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running on host: Linux x86_64 5.10.7-3-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 15 21:11:34 UTC 2021
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Found 24 CPUs.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compiled with Valgrind support: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in valgrind mode: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in VM: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running from build tree: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Optimized build: yes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: All asserts enabled.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is 9baf8a8b6aeb4e28a15a0d8c818cf597.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Session ID is 2.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/paddyl/.config/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-14.2/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

I have not found any way to fix this without completely restarting my machine. I am using Manjaro Linux 20.2.1 Nibia, and all my packages are up to date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I get this when I open 3-4 youtube tabs, but only watch one at a time. This old (2016) issue: https://github.com/evancohen/smart-mirror/issues/307 says that pulseaudio crashes whenever there is both streaming and playback. (so 3 youtube tabs are streaming one is playing.) For me, this is on Debian stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this was an issue with the USB sound interface, as I was getting the following errors in the `journalctl -xe` log:

```
kernel: usb 1-8: uac_clock_source_is_valid(): cannot get clock validity for id 18
kernel: usb 1-8: clock source 18 is not valid, cannot use
kernel: usb 1-8: 1:1: cannot get freq (v2/v3): err -110
kernel: usb 1-8: 1:1: cannot set freq 44100 (v2/v3): err -110
```

Plugging the USB output for my external DAC into a different USB port has fixed the issue for now, although I am still not sure if it won't just show up again.